# gradients in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css, gradient

I'm trying to make shiny buttons in browsers that support gradients, but never got the look I wanted in Firefox.  The image shows what they look like in chrome/safari (which is what I'm after), but I couldn't figure out how to get the distinct reflection line in Firefox (3.5+ of course).

http://karmatics.com/stuff/shiny.png http://karmatics.com/stuff/shinycss3button.html

Below is the webkit code (for the gradient), I'd like to match the look exactly in Firefox.  For the rest of the CSS (including my poor attempt at doing it in Mozilla, which isn't lickably glossy enough for my taste), view source on the page.

(BTW, I'd be thrilled if someone wanted to make it look good in IE too, but not holding my breath  :) )

**edit: mozilla answer is in there now (also at link above)**

```
<style>
div.shiny {
 background-image:
    -webkit-gradient(
        linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,
        from(rgba(255,255,255,0.5)),
        to(rgba(255,255,255,0.2)),
        color-stop(.5,rgba(255,255,255,0.3)),
        color-stop(.5,rgba(255,255,255,0.0))
        );
 background-image:
   -moz-linear-gradient (top, 
     rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 
     rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 50%, 
     rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 50%, 
     rgba(255,255,255,0.2));
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox use

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, red, white, blue);
```

or

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#000,#444 45%, #777 45%, #555);
```

you can add as many colors as you want to get the right look. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient

For IE use the filter property

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/gkyg3/1/

Comment: In my example (which is admittedly copied and altered from somewhere that I no longer can find) there is a sharp line in the middle.  The -moz technique you use doesn't seem to help with that....those colors will always blend together smoothly.  Is there no way to get the sharp line in the middle that makes it look glossy?

Comment: You need to work around that by having multiples of the same colors, ex: `background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, red,red, red, red, white, blue,blue, blue, blue, blue);`. You need to try out make your own combination to achieve the look you are after. his is the only way you can have it done with Firefox.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that color stops won't work as they do in webkit?  I was assuming I just didn't know how to use them right in moz-land.

Comment: I found it. There is a property for that in firefox so you can control how far the gradient should go. `-moz-linear-gradient(left top 315deg, orange, yellow 30%, white 40%);`

Comment: @rob, That is correct. but we can set percentages, which will work in a similar way. Did you check the last example. http://jsfiddle.net/gkyg3/1/

Comment: Sorry while you were posting the jsfiddle thing I was adapting it to make it work with mine....I got it to match exactly

Comment: Great, i also learned more about the Gradient percentages by doing the example.

Answer (score 1):

there several sites from where you can Generator gradient for mozilla,webkit & IE.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

http://gradients.glrzad.com/

http://www.display-inline.fr/projects/css-gradient/#startType=hex&startValue=aaeeff&endType=hex&endValue=3399cc

rob,it's advice for you that search before asking any the question .it's a common question.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the reflection is the harder line in the center, which you are achieving using stops, which Mozilla supposedly supports:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient

Comment: Yes I guess my problem is that I don't understand the syntax, nor the relationship to the "from" and "to", enough to get it right after a good while screwing around with it.